# Java Scanner errors

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to let the user enter a specific amount of entries. First the user would be asked the following question:

> Enter amount of students:

and he would enter a integer, now the code should ask the following questions:

> Please enter name of student 0:

After he entered the name it should ask the next question such as:

> Please enter score of the following student: name:

And he should enter the score. After this the loop should restart as often as in the first question answered.

---

Sadly the program would instantly ask the following questions:

> Please enter name of student 0:
>
> Please enter score of the following student: :

and throw a error after I entered something as you see in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

---

Does anyone know why? Here's my code:

```
package code;
import java.util.*;

public class MainCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter amount of students: ");
        int studentsAmount = input.nextInt();
        int loopRuns = 0;
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Please enter name of student " + loopRuns + ": ");
            String firstName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter score of the following student: " + firstName + ": ");
            int score = input.nextInt();
            // Do stuff with the firstname and amount
            loopRuns++;
        }while(loopRuns <= studentsAmount);
    }

}
```

Comment: Put an image I am not clicking that link.

Comment: Ask yourself: 'what if the next thing they enter isn't an int'?. Handle it by reprompting